# How to set EQ settings on pipewire?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, equalizer, pipewire

I have a graphic eq text file full of frequencies and eq values. Where and how would I insert this file in order to make it the default experience. I have been using an equalizer app until now but it has been having too many errors. I am using a ubuntu-based distro.